# Как увеличить\уменьшить значения в тексте на - 0x14?

Tags: lua

Имеется текст с тысячами значений в шестнадцатеричном формате. Например есть шестнадцатеричное значение 0x0063F3E5, надо найти все значения 0x006 и плюс 5 неизвестных знаков (0x006XXXXX) и уменьшить пять этих (XXXXX) знаков на 0x14, чтоб в итоге получилось 0x0063F3E5 - 0x14 = 0x0063F3D1. Интересует есть ли способ пересчитать значения не вручную?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот примерно так процесс замены будет выглядеть:

```
local s = [[0x0063F3E5 0x0053F3E5 0x0063F3E5]]
local delta = 0x14
local z = s:gsub("0x006(%x+)", function (x)  return  "0x006" ..string.format("%X",("0x"..x):format("%d") - delta)  end)
print(z)
```

результат:

```
0x0063F3D1 0x0053F3E5 0x0063F3D1
```